# Windows services Multiple Service Bus Subscriptions

Tags: azureservicebus

I currently have 3 windows services which listen to 3 different azure service bus subscriptions. Each windows service listens for new messages in a subscription and then launches a console application to handle the messages. Would it be possible to utilize less windows services?

Comment: if the answer is not addressing your question, provide a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have multiple [SubscriptionClients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.subscriptionclient) (or [MessageReceivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.messaging.messagereceiver)) in a single Windows Service running side by side and doing exactly the same. As long as these three services don't have a requirement to run with different credentials, should be possible.

Easiest way would be to use those clients/receivers with your callback using [OnMessage API](https://weblogs.asp.net/sfeldman/azure-service-bus-onmessage-api).